# Cannot compile and link on MacOS, code is without error - only including stdio.h & "my_header.h"

Tags: c, macos, linker

I am a bit new to programming. I started following this tutorial which has this code to complete some sudoku puzzle. I am using vim and YCM which displays most errors and problems in the code - of which there is none. I have compiled many other programs and familiar with seeing this same 'Undefined symbols' error when I forget to include -lsome_library when compiling. This project is using plain C.

I am aware that this code doesn't do anything at the moment but I just want it to compile.

My setup consists of:

```
OS:
macOS Monterey Version 12.3.1

gcc -v:
Apple clang version 13.1.6 (clang-1316.0.21.2.3)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin21.4.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin

ld -v
@(#)PROGRAM:ld  PROJECT:ld64-762
BUILD 12:49:00 Mar 30 2022
configured to support archs: armv6 armv7 armv7s arm64 arm64e arm64_32 i386 x86_64 x86_64h armv6m armv7k armv7m armv7em
LTO support using: LLVM version 13.1.6, (clang-1316.0.21.2.3) (static support for 28, runtime is 28)
TAPI support using: Apple TAPI version 13.1.6 (tapi-1316.0.7.3)
```

My problem seems to be something to do with the linker. I get this compiler error:

```
me@Me-MacBook-Pro C % gcc -Wall -Werror suduko.c -o suduko
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_clearCell", referenced from:
      _hasSolution in suduko-7e8bef.o
  "_getFreeCell", referenced from:
      _hasSolution in suduko-7e8bef.o
  "_isFull", referenced from:
      _hasSolution in suduko-7e8bef.o
  "_isLegal", referenced from:
      _hasSolution in suduko-7e8bef.o
  "_readGame", referenced from:
      _main in suduko-7e8bef.o
  "_setCell", referenced from:
      _hasSolution in suduko-7e8bef.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Here is the source:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "SudukoGrid.h"

#define MIN_VALUE '1'
#define MAX_VALUE '9'
#define EMPTY_VALUE '.'
#define NUM_VALUES (MAX_VALUE-MIN_VALUE+1)
#define GRID_SIZE (NUM_VALUES*NUM_VALUES)
#define MAX_CELL (GRID_SIZE - 1)

#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0

typedef char value;
typedef int cell;
typedef value sudukoGrid [GRID_SIZE];

int hasSolution (sudukoGrid game);

int main( int argc, const char *argv[]) {

    //testSudukoGrid();

    sudukoGrid sample;
    readGame (sample);

    // showGame (sample);
    if( hasSolution(sample)) {
    //showGame (sample);
    }

    return 0;
}

int hasSolution (sudukoGrid game) {

    int solved;
    cell candidateCell;
    value trialValue;

    if(isFull (game)) {
    solved = TRUE;
    } else {
    candidateCell = getFreeCell (game);
    trialValue =  MIN_VALUE;
    solved = FALSE;

    while (!solved && (trialValue <= MAX_VALUE)) {
        if(isLegal (game, candidateCell, trialValue)) {
            setCell (game, candidateCell, trialValue);

            if (hasSolution (game)) {
           solved = TRUE;
            } else {
            clearCell (game, candidateCell);
        }
        }
        trialValue ++;
    }
    }

    return solved;

}
```

Here is the included header:

```
#define MIN_VALUE '1'
#define MAX_VALUE '9'
#define EMPTY_VALUE '.'
#define NUM_VALUES (MAX_VALUE-MIN_VALUE+1)
#define GRID_SIZE (NUM_VALUES*NUM_VALUES)
#define MAX_CELL (GRID_SIZE - 1)

typedef char value;
typedef int cell;
typedef value sudukoGrid [GRID_SIZE];

void readGame (sudukoGrid game);
void showGame (sudukoGrid game);
void setCell (sudukoGrid game, cell location, value digit);
value getCell (sudukoGrid game, cell location);
void clearCell (sudukoGrid game, cell location);
int isFull (sudukoGrid game);
cell getFreeCell (sudukoGrid game);
int isLegal (sudukoGrid game, cell location, value canidateDigit);
```

If I remove the included file and paste the declarations into the main file I still get the linking errors.

Comment: What type of your Mac? M1? or Intel?

Comment: You actually have to have those functions in the code somewhere. You can put in stubs for testing.

Comment: john elemans, thanks for the answer. It works now.

Answer (score 0):

Per John elemans response it now compiles. Here is the new code for anyone else wondering of the solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "SudukoGrid.h"

#define MIN_VALUE '1'
#define MAX_VALUE '9'
#define EMPTY_VALUE '.'
#define NUM_VALUES (MAX_VALUE-MIN_VALUE+1)
#define GRID_SIZE (NUM_VALUES*NUM_VALUES)
#define MAX_CELL (GRID_SIZE - 1)

#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0

typedef char value;
typedef int cell;
typedef value sudukoGrid [GRID_SIZE];

int hasSolution (sudukoGrid game);

int main( int argc, const char *argv[]) {

    //testSudukoGrid();

    sudukoGrid sample;
    readGame (sample);

    // showGame (sample);
    if( hasSolution(sample)) {
    //showGame (sample);
    }

    return 0;
}

int hasSolution (sudukoGrid game) {

    int solved;
    cell candidateCell;
    value trialValue;

    if(isFull (game)) {
    solved = TRUE;
    } else {
    candidateCell = getFreeCell (game);
    trialValue =  MIN_VALUE;
    solved = FALSE;

    while (!solved && (trialValue <= MAX_VALUE)) {
        if(isLegal (game, candidateCell, trialValue)) {
            setCell (game, candidateCell, trialValue);

            if (hasSolution (game)) {
           solved = TRUE;
            } else {
            clearCell (game, candidateCell);
        }
        }
        trialValue ++;
    }
    }

    return solved;

}

void readGame (sudukoGrid game) {};
void showGame (sudukoGrid game) {};
void setCell (sudukoGrid game, cell location, value digit) {};
value getCell (sudukoGrid game, cell location) {
    return 1;
} ;
void clearCell (sudukoGrid game, cell location) {}
int isFull (sudukoGrid game) {
    return 1;
};
cell getFreeCell (sudukoGrid game) {
    return 1;
}
int isLegal (sudukoGrid game, cell location, value canidateDigit) {
    return 1;
}
```